# jwt/tymon expiry time not working

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am using jwt/tymon package in laravel. And just for test purposes I set the ttl in config/jwt.php to 1 (1 minute). So I do login, receive a new token, and then wait more than one minute before do another call. And when I make a new call, providing the token received in the login, i receive the response with the data asked in the request. But what I was hopping to get in the response was token_expired.

If the ttl is set to one minute, all calls made one minute after the creation of the token should be answered with token_expired, no?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind is that someone once said, "you should rerun your application when you make changes to the configuration file" If you are using `php artisan serve` you might need to stop and restart.